# Where would tables that are not normalised be applicable?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, metadata, business-intelligence

Is it ever best practise or recommended to use a table of the following?

```
 id, uid, fieldname, fieldvalue
    4, 12, gender, male
    5, 12, age, 21-30
    6, 12, location, 5
    7, 13, gender, female
    8, 13, age, 31-40
    9, 13, location, 5
    10, 14, gender, female
    11, 14, age, 31-40
    12, 14, location, 6
    13, 15, gender, male
    14, 15, age, 21-30
    15, 15, location, 7
```

It is not normalised and you cannot specify the data type of the field.

Would the following not be better

```
id, uid, gender, age, location
4, 12, male, 21-30, 5
5, 13, female, 31-40, 5
6, 14, female, 31-40, 6
7, 15, male, 21-30, 7
```

I want to know if you can ever justify having such a table in a database, I know that the first method may be easier to add more fields (instead of altering the database) and will probably remove all null values.

However one cannot specify the datatype and you will have to convert from string every time you want to use the data.

So is there ever a scenario where the first table is considered the best practice or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on a system that uses that method will make you lose your sanity. The complexity of the queries required in order to perform basic tasks is dreadful, and performance is a nightmare.

Here's one man's experience: https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize the initial setup by adding another table:

```
fieldnames (fnid, name)
fieldvalues (id, uid, fnid, value, unique(uid,fnid))
```

However, I would recommend against it because of its complexity -- it's much easier to use a single table unless you are going to be adding and/or removing fields very frequently or there could be a large disparity in which rows get which fields (in which case you should probably rethink redesigning your DB and application).

Answer (score 0):

The first type of structure you describe is quite common in applications where attributes are not known in advance. For example, you might be developing a system where a user can save details about contacts. You might know some of the details that will be stored, but not others. So, you might allow the user to define custom-attributes for a contact.

Of course, this type of design means that one loses database-applied checks, and has to rely on application-applied checks. That's a con, but should not be a deal-breaker if the flexibility is really required.